# Como fazer uma transição de textos (em array) dentro de um elemento HTML com fade e delay?

Tags: javascript, transição

Resumindo: quero um algoritmo similar à transição de legendas mas sem audio ou vídeo, apenas uma transição de textos com *delay* e *fade*.

Cenário:

Tenho um *array* denteado com 20 *arrays*, cada *array* é composto de 2 valores: o **primeiro** contendo a *string* da legenda e o **segundo** contendo o *delay* em *milisegundos*.

**ps**: O motivo dessa estrutura é pra facilitar a manutenção através de JSON.

Exemplo:

```
  var arrLegendas = [
                        ["legenda 1, blablalba", 2000],
                        ["legenda 2, blablalbaaldaldald", 4000],
                        ["legenda 3, bla", 1000],
                        ["legenda 4, blablalbaasdasd", 3000],
                    ]
```

[**Tentei isso e quase obtive êxito**](http://jsfiddle.net/tf1yyLg4/2/). Funciona perfeitamente se tirar os fades (apenas a transição dos textos 'solida'). Com os fades, depois da décima transição(aproximadamente), os textos começam a ser colocados depois do fade não sei porque.

Comment: vê se isso ajuda você http://jsfiddle.net/W47QV/4/

Comment: @kabstergo Cada legenda tem que ter seu tempo próprio de duração. Tentei adaptar mas não funcionou http://jsfiddle.net/W47QV/286/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue a solução cada elemento com seu respectivo tempo de transição:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var items = [["Two",2000], ["Three",3000], ["Four",4000], ["Five",5000], ["Six",6000], ["One",1000]];
  var $text = $('#div1 span');

  function loop(index) {
    $text.html(items[index][0]);
    $text.fadeIn();
    $text.delay(items[index][1]).fadeOut(function(){
        if(index < (items.length - 1)){
            loop(++index);
        }
        else loop(0);
    });
  }

  loop(0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hs0x7jey/